# Let $X$ and $Y$ be non-empty sets and let $f:X \rightarrow Y$. Prove that $ f^{ −1} :P(Y ) → P(X) $ is injective if, and only if, $f$ is surjective.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So the idea that I am having is, saying that we let f be surjective, and we would prove that $f^{-1}$ is injective. What is confusing me is how I would word my proof and how I would represent it. I am starting it off with Let X and Y be non-empty sets, and let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a function. Now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does it mean for $f^{-1}$ to be injective, as a function $\mathcal{P}(Y)\to \mathcal{P}(X)$? It means that for all $A,B\subseteq Y$, if $f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(B)$, then $A=B$. You have to show:
$$
\it\text{$f\colon X\to Y$ is surjective $\iff$ for all $A,B\subseteq Y$, if $f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(B)$, then $A=B$.}
$$
($\implies\!$)
Suppose $f$ is surjective, and suppose that $A,B\subseteq Y$ and $f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(B)$. If $a\in A$, then there is some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=a$, so $x\in f^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(B)$. Thus $f(x)\in B$, i.e. $a\in B$. But $a$ was arbitrary, so we've just shown that $A\subseteq B$. By the same argument, $B\subseteq A$, so $A=B$.

($\,\Longleftarrow\,$) Suppose $f^{-1}$ is injective. Let $y\in Y$. Then $\{y\} \ne \emptyset$, and both are subsets of $Y$. Thus,
$$
f^{-1}(\{y\})\ne f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset.
$$
So $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is nonempty — that is, there's some $x\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$. In other words, $f(x) = y$. As $y$ was arbitrary, $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I understand that part, but how would I prove that it only occurs when f is surjective? How do I prove that there will always be f(A)=B ect

Comment: That was an answer in progress. See now. You're confusing yourself with your notation. Don't use $A,B$ as arguments to $f$, use uppercase letters from the beginning of the alphabet for subsets of $X$ and $Y$ (things that can be arguments to $f^{-1}$), and use lowercase letters for members of $X$ and $Y$ (things that can be arguments to $f$).

Comment: Great really makes a lot of sense, thank you so much BrianO!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that clarified things.