# for functions $f: A \to B$,$g:P(A) \to P(B)$ when $g(Y) = f^{-1}[Y]$, prove that $f$ is surjective iff $g$ is injective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: A \to B$ be some function, and we declare $g:P(A) \to P(B)$ by $g(Y) = f^{-1}[Y]$. I need to prove that  $f$ is surjective iff $g$ is injective.

So I started with the first direction, I assume $f$ is surjective and want to prove that $g$ is injective. So I assume $g(X) = g(Y)$ for some subgroups of $B$, which means that $f^{-1}[X] = f^{-1}[Y]$. But I get stuck. I don't see how the fact that $f$ is surjective helps me here,  since the only thing I can conclude is that  $f^{-1}[X]$ and  $f^{-1}[Y]$ are not empty.

I am also having trouble with the second direction.

Moreover, does $f$ being surjective imply $g$ is surjective?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557548/let-x-and-y-be-non-empty-sets-and-let-fx-rightarrow-y-prove-that-f?rq=1 (although that question assumes the domain and codomain are nonempty, so to handle *this* question you need to think for another moment or two about the case of the empty domain and nonempty codomain).

Comment: I think $g$ is supposed to be $P(B)\to P(A)$.

Comment: The answer to the final part of your question is no: take $f : \{1, 2\} \to \{1\}$, then $f$ is surjective but $g$ is not.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve it